# Show Estimated remaining time to train a model Tensorflow with large epochs

Tags: tensorflow

Is it possible to show the Estimated remaining time to train a model Tensorflow with large epochs

```
model.compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(xs, ys, epochs = 500, verbose=1 ) # verbose 1 means progress bar
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CS

Comment: Maybe you can use the training time of last epoch to estimate the remaining time. Or, more accurately, use the exp moving average of last 10 (say) epochs to estimate the remaining time.

Comment: the model.fit() method returns metrics and loss and not the times. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model . I wish there was a way to do that! I guess you are telling me to use ARMA, or a time series forecasting method.

Comment: You can customize callbacks that return you times...

Comment: I suppose you are talking about https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback. Can you elaborate more on this please? Train on 62788 samples
Epoch 1/2
27904/62788 [============>.................] - ETA: 44s - loss: 7.6488 - acc: 0.0374

Comment: Des anyone know any example on how to do this please?